System of rotation in the Indian context
I read the Wikipedia page on the "rotation government" style of government. I cant find any examples of this in the Indian context, and strongly believe no such examples exist. But I would love for someone familiar with Indian politics to educate me on the matter. My question is in the context of this style of government being employed in the state governments, but any examples are welcome.
On a side note, if no such examples exist - does this prove the rotation form of government is inherently unconstitutional and cannot directly be employed in India, but rather is just a legal loophole which while technically possible is highly unplausible?
I have attached the Wiki link below:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_government
Thanks!

Of note and not mentioned in the Wikipedia article is the rotating presidency of the Council of the European Union. Also, Malaysia in addition to having experience with rotation government also basically has rotating monarchy with state monarches in the federal country taking turns as the national monarch. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarchies_of_Malaysia

A coalition agreement to change prime minister before the next election is not inherently unconstitutional if the coalition has a majority and can choose who the prime minister is.  But it typically requires two similarly sized parties to agree to the rotation as a condition of the coalition (which failed to happen in Germany) and may turn out to be unenforceable when the time comes for the rotation (as happened in Malaysia).  Perhaps India has not yet been in a situation where it matters.

Article 75 of the Indian Constitution does not outright forbid a rotation government in the office of Prime Minister and other Union Council of Minister positions, but it does require the cooperation of the President, which would ordinarily be freely given. See Article 75(2). State governments are similar.
So, while rotation government isn't expressly contemplated, and I am not aware of any instance when it has been used at the Union or State level in India, there is no great constitutional barrier to it.
In practice, even though the BJP does not have an outright majority, the Council of Ministers is very disproportionately made up of BJP members, more so than would be expected given the number of MPs that it has in parliament. So, the political culture seems ill-suited to rotation government.

Some additional references - in the indian parliamentary system, the post of the PM is a titular one as s/he is considered 'first among equals'. Thus, as you rightly pointed out, the constitution places no bar on "rotating" the PM / CM, and anyone with a majority support can become the PM / CM anytime. In fact, in coalition politics in India, rotation of the PM / CM post is a common negotiating point. E.g. Shiv Sena talks of CM by rotation, JMM now demands rotational Chief Ministership or A bad case of politics

And INDI alliance wants to rotate the Prime Minister's post among its leaders every year, claims PM Modi.
